# controlsfx.GridView align left, how to make it align center

Tags: gridview, javafx, groovy, controlsfx

here is my code:

```
    def list = FXCollections.observableArrayList([])
    GridView<Color> g = new GridView<>(list);
    g.setCellFactory(new Callback<GridView<Color>, GridCell<Color>>() {
        public GridCell<Color> call(GridView<Color> gridView) {
            return new ColorGridCell();
        }
    });
    Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        list.add(new Color(r.nextDouble(), r.nextDouble(), r.nextDouble(), 1.0));
    }
```

see my screenshot, the left padding and right padding is diff, how to align Gridview to center

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`GridView` flows cells automatically based on its width and height. The reason you have more space on the right is that the column of cell does not quite fit into it yet. Try to resize the window horizontally and you will see what I mean.

Comment: resize window maybe cause whole layout is messy, can i align GridView with setAlignment(Pos.CENTER)?

Comment: You can probably fix the width on the `GridView` component and add it as child to another layout, such as `StackPane`.

Comment: I guess that's a no xD